# Jquery Layer slider full height or full screen slider / possible?

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design, slider

How can i set the website slider to change height when the height of monitor resolution changes? e.g. in 1920-1366-1024 resolution monitors.
website: [Link](http://cfnic.com/)

layer slider: [Link](http://codecanyon.net/item/layerslider-responsive-jquery-slider-plugin/922100)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS Media queries.
@media

Comment: I've used. But in some desktop sizes will not work correctly.There is another way?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the best example for the full screen slider, http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/BackgroundSlideshow/

Comment: Please, if you like the solution to the desired website( [link](http://cfnic.com) ). Provide.

Comment: sure, Please use this css, div.ls-slide{height:900px!important;width:100%!important}
div.ls-slide img{height:900px!important; width:100%!important}